# How to get Azure Functions to run a durable function that dynamically fetches the activity function

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am trying to create a durable function that starts a different activity depending on the URL parameter given by the user. I am using this [code sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/blob/dev/samples-v2/blueprint/durable_blueprints.py) as an example.

This is what I have so far:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
from objects.main import insert_new_usu_data, backup_usu
import json
import traceback

bp = df.Blueprint()

@bp.route(route="orchestrators/{functionName}")
@bp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def durable_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest, client):
    function_name = req.route_params.get('functionName')
    instance_id = await client.start_new(orchestrator_function_name='orchestrator_function', input={'name': function_name})
    response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return response


@bp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    activity_function_name = context.get_input()['name']
    result = yield context.call_activity(activity_function_name, None)

    return result


@bp.activity_trigger(input_name="context")
def neuUSUVertraege():
    try:
        insert_new_usu_data()
        return "USU Vertragsdaten übertragen."
    except Exception as e:
        return "Error: {e}"


@bp.activity_trigger(input_name="context")  
def usuBackup():
    try:
        response = backup_usu()
        return json.dumps(response)
    except Exception as e:
        error = traceback.format_exc()
        logging.error(f"Error: {error}")
        return f"Error: {error}"
```

But for some reason my code isn't fetching the right activity function as hoped. Actually, the entire durable function appear to not do anything at all. Any suggestions on what could be missing?

Comment: Have you double-checked what the value of `activity_function_name` is inside the orchestrator?

Comment: Yes, but as it turns out, there is no keyword parameter in V2...it needs to go in the third position...whoever came up with the documentation should take a crash course on writing documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out, the documentation is not clear and you just have to kind of remember what you need to do

orchestrator_function_name does not exist, you just have to remember that  client.start_new is followed by orchestrator_name, instance_id, input'

Also context needs to be passed to the function even if you are not going to use it.

This is the final code

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
from objects.main import insert_new_usu_data, backup_usu
import json
import traceback

bp = df.Blueprint()

@bp.route(route="orchestrators/{functionName}")
@bp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def durable_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest, client):
    function_name = req.route_params.get('functionName')
    # generate a new instance id
    instance_id = await client.start_new('orchestrator_function', None, {'name': function_name})
    response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return response


@bp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    activity_function_name = context.get_input()['name']
    result = yield context.call_activity(activity_function_name, None)

    return result


@bp.activity_trigger(input_name="context")
def neuUSUVertraege(context):
    try:
        insert_new_usu_data()
        return "USU Vertragsdaten übertragen."
    except Exception as e:
        return "Error: {e}"


@bp.activity_trigger(input_name="context")  
def usuBackup(context):
    try:
        response = backup_usu()
        return json.dumps(response)
    except Exception as e:
        error = traceback.format_exc()
        logging.error(f"Error: {error}")
        return f"Error: {error}"
```

Figuring it out took hours, which I could have saved if Microsoft would only clarify the object properties in its documentation...